# Clojure compiler error

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors

I'm working on a clojure program that includes these lines of code:

```
(defn makeStruct 
 "Take a line of input and return a starbucks-struct"
 [input]
 (let[(apply struct storeinfo (clojure.string/split input #","))]
 )
```

)

And am getting this compiler error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: let requires an even number of forms in binding vector (clojureHW.clj:24)
```

I am very new to clojure and am not entirely sure what I am doing, but in this case input is a string and I am splitting it into a vector to initialize my struct. Am I using the syntax of `let` incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let requires an even numbers of forms, because it binds values to locals:

```
(let [x 10,
      y (+ x 20)]
   ; do something with x and y here
   (* x y))
```

Please read the documentation here:
[http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(let%20%5Bbindings*%20%5D%20exprs*)](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5Bbindings*%20%5D%20exprs*%29)

Comment: Yes I understand that and have already been over that documentation page. I count two parts to the let statement (apply struct storeinfo) and (split input #",") What's wrong with it?

Comment: (apply struct storeinfo) is not a symbol, like x or y in the example I gave you. Btw, you have (apply struct storeinfo (clojure.string/split input #",")), not (apply struct storeinfo) and (split input #",").

Comment: The way I understood it, (apply struct storeinfo) would return a storeinfo struct that would then be split by the following statement, (split input #",") Is let the wrong keyword/operation to use here?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you mean something like -> or ->>, see for example http://blog.fogus.me/2009/09/04/understanding-the-clojure-macro/. But if (apply struct storeinfo) is the first form that will be executed, I would expect storeinfo to be something you have defined before or a parameter of makeStruct.

Comment: Hey. If you're still watching this I posted another question about a clojure compiler error. No pressure if you can't answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have misunderstanding on the lisp way handling return values and bindings.

Everything in a pair of parens an expression returns a value that value can be uses by a in a other expression or be bound to a symbol.

You have this

```
(apply struct storeinfo (clojure.string/split input #","))
```

This returnes on value because there is only one expression. Its quite simple just count the outher most parens.

And since you have nothing else in the let you have a odd number of forms (expression) in let.

Answer (score 0):

The "binding" side of a `let` expression may only have symbols and destructuring forms, such as vectors and maps.  The binding side of `let` can't evaluate an expression like `(apply struct storeinfo)`.